# Ignoring whitespace in ext js combo box autocomplete

Tags: javascript, extjs

In my application, we are using extjs for generating grids. there are multiple autocompletes there. For many of the autocompletes, data is hard coded in the corrosponding store js.

Issue is when user types additional spaces then autocomplete doesn't work. I have to fix this issue. I tried stripCharsRe, but it is not an solution, because i can not restrict user from entering space. I need to perform trim some where in between. Any suggestion?

Comment: So you want to convert two continous spaces into one space..?

Comment: No. requirement is like this. suppose user enter - "Hello World ". Data should be as it is in the grid, but when it check for autocomplete in the store than it should match for "Hello World".

Comment: can you show your auto complete code?